# How i can stop processing of htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, apache2.4

I've got two directives in my htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^(it|en|de)/(.*) $2?lng=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That means: for all url with start with it, en, de set url variables "lng" to $lang

Now, i want that all pages that didn't start with a language code to be redirected to  /it:

I try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(it|en|de)/{0,1}(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but when i call:

```
http://HOST/my-page
```

on url, i get, with a "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS":

```
http://HOST/it/my-page?lng=it&lng=it&{many-others-lng=it}
```

the word "/it" is added correctly at the beginning of the url, but also infinity "lng=it"

I use "L" flag: this shoud stop processing the rule set.

Any hint?

**EDIT:**
Add my full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(it|en|de)/(.*) $2?lng=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^catalogue-men$ views/main/pages/index.cfm?gen=1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/it/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What would you want to happen if a client sends `/it/my-page?lng=en`?

Comment: @DusanBajic
 Redirect to: /it/my-page

Comment: You have a loop somewhere. The error message is pretty clear. Can you post the full .htaccess file ? The order of directives is important.

Comment: thanks. i add my full .htaccess to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember that `mod_rewrite` runs in loop until there is no rule that fires. You are getting redirect loop because first rule is removing `/it/` from start of URI and `301` rule is adding it in front.

1. Reordering your rules
2. Using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI`
3. Add `/catalogue-men` in your skip condition

This .htaccess should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(?:it|catalogue-men)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(it|en|de)/(.*) $2?lng=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^catalogue-men$ views/main/pages/index.cfm?gen=1 [QSA,NC,L]
```